# OAuth token (OAuth-apis) validation with HAProxy

Tags: validation, oauth, haproxy

Can anybody point out to OAuth token (OAuth-apis) validation with HAProxy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OAuth token validation from HAProxy or Apache mod\_proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375442/oauth-token-validation-from-haproxy-or-apache-mod-proxy)